# How to use jet engine to read data from excel in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, excel, visual-studio-2008

how can I create a connection to excel file and view the result in vb. 
I am using visual studio 2008, I have been trying to look for answers around but could not find one that teaches step by step.And what references do I need to use? 
Thanks in advance.

Regards
Jason

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to treat the contained worksheets of a workbook as tables consider using an OLEDB driver to query the data as you would a database.  It's cleaner than Excel automation if you only care about the data.  Check out [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excel_using_oledb.aspx).